# Using set_yticklabels results in horizontally aligned tick labels, instead of vertically

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this plot:

[image: Plot]

And this is the code to set the y tick labels:

```
B= np.zeros((1,8))  #np.zeros((1,(len(K_frs)-1)/5))
for j in range(8): #(len(K_frs)-1)/5):
    B[0,j]=(round((1/K_frs[len(K_frs)-(5*j)-1]),2))
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(B)
```

How can I fix y tick labels to vertical format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is of shape `(1, 8)`, but [`set_yticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html) expects a "list of string labels". So you could just flatten the array:

```
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(B.flat)
```